# thymeleaf - passing a Selection Variable Expression *{foo} to an Expression Utility Object

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, spring-el

I have a spring backed form with a model object Foo that contains Bar

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/some/action}" th:object="${foo}" method="post">
```

now, I would like to do something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="bar.createdAt" name="bar.createdAt" th:value="*{bar.createdAt} ? ${#dates.format(bar.createdAt, #messages.msg('app.dateformat.datetime'))}"/>
```

but the following parsing exeption is thrown:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#dates.format(bar.createdAt, #messages.msg('app.dateformat.datetime'))" (registration:93)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
root cause

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#dates.format(bar.createdAt, #messages.msg('app.dateformat.datetime'))" (registration:93)
    org.thymeleaf.spring4.expression.SpelVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SpelVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:161)
    org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariable(VariableExpression.java:154)
    org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:59)
root cause

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 7): Property or field 'createdAt' cannot be found on null
    org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:211)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:85)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:43)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:341)
```

I've already tried: 
`...#dates.format(*{bar.createdAt}..., ...#dates.format(__*{bar.createdAt}__...`but none has worked out.

the same without the form (directly accessing view model object) works fine.

Any idea what would be the right construct?
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of :

`${#dates.format(bar.createdAt, #messages.msg('app.dateformat.datetime'))}`

Change it to :

`*{#dates.format(bar.createdAt, #messages.msg('app.dateformat.datetime'))}`

So that the utility object will work on the `bar` property of the last selected object which is the form backing object, `${foo}`, in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I think the clue is in the line:

```
Property or field 'createdAt' cannot be found on null
```

Are you sure that `bar` is not null?

Comment: as I have written, I tried with `#dates.format(__*{bar.createdAt}__` as well and the preprocessed date was injected as a string. So I am sure it is not null. I event went further and did some thing like this:
`th:value="*{bar.createdAt}"` which gave me the unformated datetime value

Comment: I think you might need to post the relevant parts of your Java code too. Forms and model objects are subtly different, so I wonder if that's where the problem lies?